# python re.sub problems backreferencing from a function

Tags: python, regex

I want to 'join' certain numbers, that clearly should be together, although I don't want them to join every number.

What I have:

```
'Canesten 1 500 mg meka kapsula za rodnicui'
'Clexane 10 000 IU (100 mg)/1 ml otopina za injekciju'
'Humulin M3 100 IU/ml suspenzija za injekciju u ulošku'
'Docile10 000 IU/ml oralne kapi, otopina'
'POLYGYNAX 35 000 IU / 35 000 IU / 100 000 IU kapsula za rodnicu, meka'
'Prostin E2 2 mg gel za rodnicu'
'Silapen K 1 000 000 IU filmom obložene tablete'
```

I want to have:

```
'Canesten 1500 mg meka kapsula za rodnicui'
'Clexane 10000 IU (100 mg)/1 ml otopina za injekciju'
'Humulin M3 100 IU/ml suspenzija za injekciju u ulošku'
'Docile10000 IU/ml oralne kapi, otopina'
'POLYGYNAX 35000 IU / 35000 IU / 100000 IU kapsula za rodnicu, meka'
'Prostin E2 2 mg gel za rodnicu'
'Silapen K 1000000 IU filmom obložene tablete'
```

It may be easier to see which ones I'm trying to join here: https://regex101.com/r/Ht9ZVi/1

I can match each one of the numbers I want to join using `([^a-zA-Z](?:\d+\s+)*\d+\s\d+0{2})`, but because this regex is not perfect regarding the blank spaces I thought about using a function to only remove the blank spaces between numbers.

```
def spaces(s):
    return re.sub('(?<=\d) (?=\d)', '', s)

cr['Name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"([^a-zA-Z](?:\d+\s*)*\d+\s\d+0{2})", spaces(r'\1'), x))
```

This returns the strings unaltered, what am I doing wrong?
I know this is a common question, and the solution is probably really simple but I can't wrap my head around it..

Comment: Second argument of "re.sub" can be a function object but you call the function and use the returned string as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you want to match a leading single char other than a-zA-Z with `[^a-zA-Z]`, but you can assert not an uppercase A-Z directly to the left instead to account for `Docile10 000`

Then you don't need a capture group and you could match the digits with at least 1 space in between followed by asserting one of the allowed units.

Then remove the spaces from the match with `.group(0)`

This part `[^\S\n]+` matches whitespace chars without newlines. If you want to allow crossing newlines, you can use `\s+` instead

```
(?<![A-Z])\d+(?:[^\S\n]+\d+)+(?=[^\S\n]*(?:mg|IU)\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xvwlsR/1)

You can also omit the assertion for the unit at the end for the current example data:

```
(?<![A-Z])\d+(?:[^\S\n]+\d+)+
```

Example

```
strings = [
    'Canesten 1 500 mg meka kapsula za rodnicui',
    'Clexane 10 000 IU (100 mg)/1 ml otopina za injekciju',
    'Humulin M3 100 IU/ml suspenzija za injekciju u ulošku',
    'Docile10 000 IU/ml oralne kapi, otopina',
    'POLYGYNAX 35 000 IU / 35 000 IU / 100 000 IU kapsula za rodnicu, meka',
    'Prostin E2 2 mg gel za rodnicu',
    'Silapen K 1 000 000 IU filmom obložene tablete'
]

pattern = r"(?<![A-Z])\d+(?:[^\S\n]+\d+)+(?=[^\S\n]*(?:mg|IU)\b)"

for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: re.sub(r"\s+", "", x.group()), s))
```

Output

```
Canesten 1500 mg meka kapsula za rodnicui
Clexane 10000 IU (100 mg)/1 ml otopina za injekciju
Humulin M3 100 IU/ml suspenzija za injekciju u ulošku
Docile10000 IU/ml oralne kapi, otopina
POLYGYNAX 35000 IU / 35000 IU / 100000 IU kapsula za rodnicu, meka
Prostin E2 2 mg gel za rodnicu
Silapen K 1000000 IU filmom obložene tablete
```

Comment: That does make the output identical to the OP's wishes, although I still find it shaky to assume that numbers prefixed with lowercase letters are allowed to be joined. The OP better make some clarification here. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @blhsing I don't have much more cases other than the ones I showed here, and fortunately the numbers prefixed with lowercase letters are allowed to be joined :) thank you both for your responses